# Cross Platform, Cross .NET versions Hash-function

Tags: c#, hash, cross-platform, hashcode

I need a cross platform, cross .NET versions hash function.
Note that most\any regular hashing may produce different results on different machines, probably as a result of different settings on the OS, the compiler used, 32\64 bit, etc.

What I need is an all-around C# method that will hash a string but that the hash value will be the same when produced on any of the many machines I have that take part in my system. (They all use .NET 3.5 and above).

Comment: maybe MD5 / SHA1? crc-16 / crc-32?

Comment: Could you please tell us the purpose, you need the hash function for? Should you e.g. need it to hash passwords, then every calculation _should_ return a different result, because of the unique salt. So are you looking for a cryptographic hash function, or just a function to feed a dictionary?

Comment: A central bank holds files generated by clients.
Each client, before generating the file, check if it exists in the bank application.
If it exists, meaning another client has already created that file, and uploaded it to the bank. To check if it exists, the client hashed a looooooong set of params, and asks the bank if the hash key already exists in the bank.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If performance is not an issue, try one of the cryptographic hash functions that come with the .NET Framework library: **MD5, [SHA256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), [RIPEMD160](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIPEMD)**. If performance is an issue, you could perhaps go for something like **MurMurHash3**. All of these are dependent only on the input.

(If you want to hash for security purposes, it's worth noting that you should only use cryptographic hash functions and that [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) and [older versions of SHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA1) have known vulnerabilities and should be avoided.)

Comment: from previous experience with MD5 and SHA I've found them to be not cross platform compatible!
Are you sure that the other's you have mentioned ARE?

Comment: @EdoTzumer All cryptographic hash functions that I know *are* platform and language independent. If you've gotten different MD5 (for example) hashes, it simply means you didn't provide the same input or you didn't read the output in the same way. Language and platform have nothing to do with it, unless there's an implementation error in a specific platform, in which case it's not really MD5.

Comment: @ Throdoros If that was 100% true, that'd be nice. However, you can simply check .NET SHA-1 for example on 32 bit and 64 bit machines to see that you get different results

Comment: @EdoTzumer I've just tested on Windows 7 and Windows Server, 32-bit and 64-bit, .NET Framework versions 3.5 CP and 4.0 and the results are (unsurprisingly) the same. Would you mind showing us (in your question) a very small code sample that demonstrates different hashing behavior on different machines?

Comment: The answer is firstly - No. Since the code is in a project I've done for the previous company I worked at. The different results were receive then with SHA-1, and they differed between WinServer2003 32bit and Win7 64 bit.
The fact that you got the same results now, definitely does not indicate that they always will be. If of course you can find a statement for that in MSDN or any formal article, I'd be glad to be referenced to it.
If I may ask, what makes you sure that you will get the same results invariantly of the OS, Platfrom, etc.?

Comment: @EdoTzumer Well, if you can't reproduce it, I'm afraid you'll have to accept that the code you left at the previous company is wrong - in the sense that it didn't really hash the input you thought it hashed. All hash functions mentioned here yield a well-defined result for any given input, regardless of architecture, OS, runtime version, language or compiler options. Note the *"well-defined"* part: All hash functions have *specific definitions* and none that I know of depends on the things you mentioned.

Comment: @EdoTzumer Regarding references supporting what I'm saying, you can start at the Wikipedia descriptions of the mentioned hash functions (I've added links), or anywhere else you trust and see that the specifications of the hash functions leave no room for the factors you're concerned about.

Comment: @EdoTzumer MD5/SHA/etc wouldn't be very good algorithms if the result was dependant on anything other than just the inputs.  You can trust a correctly implemented hashing algorithm to produce the same result regardless of OS/architecture/language.  Note that they return a byte[] array - perhaps the difference you saw was in the string representation of that data.